# Is there a console command to switch the left and right mouse buttons?

Tags: windows, command-line, mouse

My friend has a Mac mouse on a windows.

When he clicks the mouse, its a right-click because the settings are reversed.

Is there a console command to switch it back? Seeing as he can't fix it with his current mouse, because he can't click the appropriate elements in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't he use the keyboard to get to the location in Control Panel to change the settings?

For what it's worth, you type `control mouse` from the command line to get into the right place, but you can get there using the Start Menu (`Ctrl` + `Esc`) and navigating with the keyboard.

Comment: he can only right click, so it wont work.

Comment: I didn't suggest anything about the mouse. I can navigate quite comfortably with the arrows, the tab key, the space bar and the Enter key.

Answer (score 2):

Change between left and right handed and back with one script - click once it changes then click again and it changes it back vs. the RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,SwapMouseButton" which only swaps to left hand but not back

Note:: if you want to email this file after you create this into MouseHandSwitch.vbs copy the following script and save it as a .vbs file on desktop and now you get it.

```
'> Mouse change Left to Right handed
'> and repeat to set Left to Right handed again.
'> By William Anderson July 1715
Sub DoAction(str, ms)

'> Check status until ready
status = (WshShell.AppActivate)(cPanel.ProcessID)
Do Until status = true
    WScript.Sleep 100
    status = (WshShell.AppActivate)(cPanel.ProcessID)
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

if status = true then
    WshShell.SendKeys str
    WScript.Sleep ms
End if
End Sub

'> Set windows for best performance
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set cPanel = WshShell.Exec("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL main.cpl")
status = (WshShell.AppActivate)(cPanel.ProcessID)
Do Until status = true
WScript.Sleep 100
status = (WshShell.AppActivate)(cPanel.ProcessID)
WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

if status = true then
'> Send alt S to mouse panel
DoAction "%S", 20 
DoAction "{ENTER}", 20
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard way of switching mouse buttons on Windows Vista (perhaps 7) and above:

1. Windows Key
2. type "mouse"
3. Spacebar
4. Enter

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, devices, mouse, and then switch primary & secondary.

You can do it using a working mouse, or the keyboard shortcut.
(<kbd>Win</kbd> then navigate/search for Settings...)

You do not necessary need a shell command, you just need to know the [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec) that allow you to access menus and navigate...

Comment: OP specifically asked for a console command. I know you were trying to be helpful, but please don't give irrelevant answers.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Feel you free to [edit] back your post or to enhance it... Do not worry about the downvote they can change their mind once the post is edited...